# jQuery theme to mimic the Django admin interface style (using CSS)

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-admin

I use jQuery UI with my Django powered website. I like the look of Django's admin interface. How can I extend that look to my user-oriented pages on the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this jQuery theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=%22Lucida+Grande%22,%22DejaVu+Sans%22,%22Bitstream+Vera+Sans%22,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.3em&cornerRadius=0px&bgColorHeader=7ca0c7&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=75&borderColorHeader=cccccc&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=ffffff&bgTextureContent=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=cccccc&fcContent=000000&iconColorContent=bbbbcc&bgColorDefault=e6e6e6&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=75&borderColorDefault=d3d3d3&fcDefault=555555&iconColorDefault=888888&bgColorHover=dadada&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=75&borderColorHover=999999&fcHover=212121&iconColorHover=454545&bgColorActive=7ca0c7&bgTextureActive=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityActive=75&borderColorActive=aaaaaa&fcActive=ffffff&iconColorActive=ffffff&bgColorHighlight=fbf9ee&bgTextureHighlight=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fcefa1&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=2e83ff&bgColorError=fef1ec&bgTextureError=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityError=95&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=cd0a0a&iconColorError=cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=30&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px). I've mimicked the style as much as possible. You can even tweak the settings if you like.